# JQGrid : sorttype integer sort column as string

Tags: jquery, sorting, struts2, jqgrid, integer

I use a JQGrid like this:

```
<@sjg.grid id="gridtable"
dataType="json"
loadonce="true"
href="${remoteurl}"
pager="true"
gridModel="myDataList"
navigator="true"
navigatorAdd="false"
navigatorEdit="false"
navigatorDelete="false"
navigatorView="true"
navigatorRefresh="false"
navigatorSearch="false"
rowNum="20"
rownumbers="true"
rowList="10,20,30,50,100"
viewrecords="true"
multiselect="true"
autowidth="true"
shrinkToFit="true"
onCompleteTopics="loadComplete"
onFocusTopics="onSelectRow"
onSelectAllTopics="onSelectAll"
filter="true"
filterOptions="{stringResult:true}"
footerrow="true"
>

<@sjg.gridColumn name="intColumn" index="intColumn" title="Test int" sortable="true" search="true" sorttype="integer" width="30" searchoptions="{sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']}"/>
```

Then, when I sort this column, the values are sorted as string value (1 < 10 < 11 < 2... instead of 1 < 2 < 10 < 11 ...).

How to explain this behavior?

EDIT:
The generated JS of the JQGrid:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.struts2_jquery.debug = false;
jQuery.struts2_jquery.loadAtOnce = true;
jQuery.scriptPath = "/struts/";
jQuery.struts2_jquery.minSuffix = "";
jQuery.struts2_jquery.local = "fr";
jQuery.struts2_jquery.gridLocal = "fr";
jQuery.struts2_jquery.timeLocal = "fr";
jQuery.struts2_jquery.defaults.indicator="indicator";
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
jQuery.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

jQuery(document).ready(function () { 
jQuery.struts2_jquery.require("js/struts2/jquery.grid.struts2-3.1.0"+jQuery.struts2_jquery.minSuffix+".js");
var options_gridtable = {};
var options_gridtable_colmodels = new Array();
var options_gridtable_colnames = new Array();

options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn = {};
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.name = "intColumn";
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.jsonmap = "intColumn";
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.index = "intColumn";
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.width = 30;
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.editable = false;
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.sortable = true;
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.resizable = true;
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.search = true;
options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.searchoptions = {sopt:['cn','eq','ne','bw','bn','ew','en','nc']};
options_gridtable_colnames.push("Int column");
options_gridtable_colmodels.push(options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn);

options_gridtable.datatype = "json";
options_gridtable.url = "myURLAction";
options_gridtable.height = 'auto';
options_gridtable.pager = "gridtable_pager";
options_gridtable.pgbuttons = true;
options_gridtable.pginput = true;
options_gridtable.rowNum = 20;
options_gridtable.rowList = [10,20,30,50,100];
options_gridtable.viewrecords = true;
options_gridtable.autowidth = true;
options_gridtable.navigator = true;
options_gridtable.navigatoradd = false;
options_gridtable.navigatordel = false;
options_gridtable.navigatoredit = false;
options_gridtable.navigatorrefresh = false;
options_gridtable.navigatorsearch = false;
options_gridtable.navigatorview = true;

options_gridtable.loadonce = true;
options_gridtable.filter = true;
options_gridtable.filteroptions = {searchOnEnter:false};
options_gridtable.multiselect = true;
options_gridtable.shrinkToFit = true;
options_gridtable.autoencode = true;
options_gridtable.footerrow = true;
options_gridtable.rownumbers = true;
options_gridtable.onselectalltopics = "onSelectAll";


options_gridtable.colNames = options_gridtable_colnames;
options_gridtable.colModel = options_gridtable_colmodels;
options_gridtable.jsonReader = {};
options_gridtable.jsonReader.root = "myDataList";
options_gridtable.jsonReader.repeatitems = false;

options_gridtable.jqueryaction = "grid";
options_gridtable.id = "gridtable";
options_gridtable.oncom = "loadComplete";
options_gridtable.onfocustopics = "onSelectRow";

jQuery.struts2_jquery_grid.bind(jQuery('#gridtable'),options_gridtable);
```

Comment: try to add `formatter="integer"` to the column definition.

Comment: I tried to add it but the problem is still present. The only difference is that default value is now 0.

Comment: jqGrid is **JavaScript** solution. Struts2 generates some JavaScript code for you. Could you append your question with resulting JavaScript code? You can open the page source in the web browser to see it. It would be helpful to see the exact input data for the grid too. You can use Network tab of Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to see the HTTP trace and to see exact JSON data used as the input for jqGrid.

Comment: The JSON result looks like this :

    `{"JSON":"success","filters":null,"myDataList":[{"intColumn":10},{"intColumn":2},{"intColumn":1},{"intColumn":11},{"intColumn":null}],"page":1,"records":3868,"rows":20,"searchField":null,"searchOper":null,"searchString":null,"sidx":"","sord":"asc","total":194}`

Comment: You should click "edit" link below the text of your question and append your question with the information. Additionally it's require to see the JavaScript code of your page which creates jqGrid. It should look like: `jQuery("#gridtable").jqGrid({/* the options of jqGrid */});` The option should contain `colModel` and `jsonReader` (something like `jsonReader: {root: "myDataList", repeatitems: false}`), which are especially important.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for your help,
I add a part of the corresponding JS to the description.

Comment: You are welcome! You can see that `options_gridtable_colmodels_numLot` has **neither `formatter = "integer"` nor `sorttype="integer"`**. It's the reason, why sorting not work. You should analyse why you don't have the properties in `colModel`.

Comment: Yes the problem is coming from there. I notice that when I add a "formatter" property, it appears well in the generated JS .
Maybe the "sorttype" property is overloaded by an other property ?

Comment: The properties which you use in the grid plugin of struts2 has no relation to jqGrid. In any way the JavaScript code should contain `options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.sorttype = "integer";` and optionally `options_gridtable_colmodels_intColumn.formatter = "integer";`. You should verify which version of struts2-jquery and struts2-jquery-grid-plugin you use.

Comment: Indeed, I update my "jqGrid" version to 4.6.0 and the problem is solved. Thanks Oleg.